# How does DateTime.now.hour(0) get a new DateTime in nscala-time?

Tags: scala, datetime, jodatime, nscala-time

I use nsacala-time package from https://github.com/nscala-time/nscala-time.

```
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._
DateTime.now.hour(0)
res0: org.joda.time.DateTime = 2015-06-11T22:33:52.266+08:00
```

will get a new DateTime object.
But in the source,https://github.com/nscala-time/nscala-time/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/github/nscala_time/time/RichDateTime.scala ,it does not have a hour function with signature (Int).
It seems that withHour(hour: Int) do the exact work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implicit conversions everywhere (a.k.a Black Magic, a.k.a why everyone hates Scala)!!!

1. `hour` returns a `org.joda.time.DateTime.Property`.
2. `Import._` imports the [`RichDateTimeProperty`](https://github.com/nscala-time/nscala-time/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/github/nscala_time/time/RichDateTimeProperty.scala)
3. `RichDateTimeProperty` has an `apply` method defined and by default in Scala doing `something()` if `something` is not a method gets translated to `something.apply()`, so finally this method is invoked via 2 implicit conversions:

   ```
   def apply(value: Int): DateTime = underlying.setCopy(value)
   ```